# bcoin.io: Get TXs in reverse order

Tags: bcoin

I am using bcoin for a project.

I would like to retrive TXs in reverse order.

In the documentation I read that I can do that through the "reverse" query string parameter.

Anyway, the documentation doesnt provide any example of how I can pass this paramenter to the javascript API in the getTXByAddress(address) method.

If that's not an option, also the cURL way is fine.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, the reverse parameter was added recently and the example in API docs were not updated.

https://bcoin.io/api-docs/#get-tx-by-address

The method now accepts a second parameter which is an "options" object. The line in the example should look like this now:

```
const result = await client.getTXByAddress(address, {reverse: true});
```

If you want to ask more specific bcoin questions you can find the developers on IRC #bcoin or on slack: https://bcoin.io/slack-signup.html

EDIT: Actually after a second look at the client code, the new options may not be available in the JS method. So thanks for asking! I'll open a PR for this ;-)

Comment: Thanks! I ve already solved the problem the cURL way :-)